# How to use Perl Plugins in Pidgin

Tags: arch-linux, perl, pidgin

I am trying to install a perl plugin to pidgin, by placing the .pl file in the `~/.purple/plugins` directory, as described [here](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Scripting%20and%20Plugins#HowdoIusePerlscriptswithPidginFinch).

The problem is that when I put the .pl file in the directory and open the plugins dialog in Pidgin, my plugin does not appear. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

There is nothing in Help→About regarding Perl support, so I don't know whether it is enabled or not.

I am running Arch Linux and Pidgin 2.10.4.

**EDIT** As grawity pointed out below, I was looking in the wrong place for whether Perl was enabled.  It is listed as enabled.

Comment: Have you restarted Pidgin after putting the file in the plugins directory?

Comment: Side note: Your Pidgin is a few months out of date, and the rest of your system is likely to be, too.

Comment: Perl support information is in Help → Build Information, by the way.

Comment: @NDGeek Yes, I have restarted Pidgin

Comment: @grawity Thanks.  How do I update?  I have run `pacman -S pidgin` and it claims that I am up to date.  I'm pretty new to Arch.  Much more familiar with Ubuntu and Fedora.

Comment: @grawity Also, thanks for letting me know.  Perl is listed as enabled

Comment: @ewok I figured as much, but it was worth asking. Is this a custom plugin?

Comment: @NDGeek http://snarfed.org/google_talk_sms_pidgin_plugin

Comment: @ewok: `pacman -Syu` to upgrade the whole system – and better do it at least once a week since Arch changes often; the [website](https://www.archlinux.org/) has a few important posts regarding recent changes.

Comment: @grawity you got it! I needed an upgrade.  If you want to post as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to have been caused by an out-of-date system.

It's recommended to update Arch Linux at least once a week, and upgrade the entire system at once instead of cherry-picking updates.

The general command for upgrading the entire system is [**`pacman -Syu`**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta). (However, at the time of posting, the [Arch Linux website](https://www.archlinux.org/) also has several important announcements regarding recent changes.)

Comment: I'd like to note that it's generally best practice to update any OS approximately once a week, or at least once a month.